# Using Eureka with Ribbon doesn't send custom header

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix, netflix-eureka

Current project uses spring-cloud-starter-eureka version 1.0.0.RELEASE.

I am using Ribbon to connect to some other services and require a custom header.

```
@Autowired
private RestTemplate restTemplate;
. . .
ResponseEntity result = this.restTemplate.exchange("https://FooServices/foos/daily", 
        HttpMethod.GET, 
        new HttpEntity(getSpecialHeaders()), 
        FooView[].class, 
        new Object[0]);
```

The code works fine for Spring Cloud version 1.0.0. However, when I move to 1.0.1 or 1.0.2, the custom header is no longer sent.

Is there a security reason this was changed or is this a defect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [bug that has been fixed](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/350).  It just needs to be released.